# Cross platform Java app that also works with Spotify

Tags: java, spotify

I am writing a Java application that will allow for usage in Spotify and throughout a good percentage of Web browsers, and mobile operating systems. I am very new to the Spotify API.

I am looking for resources and references upon building this. I need to be able to preform a check on which application is running the app and return the appropriate functions per the application type.

Furthermore I am loading external JSON feeds from a web server into the app and need to create an array that allows the feed data to be cached into an object with which data segments can be pulled from and propagated into a div.

I have begun formatting the java that will perform these functions.  However because I have not created such a script before that should run robustly across a multitude of platforms I am somewhat coding in the dark.

Is there anyone out there who has written a similar Java application & could provide some feed back?

Comment: *"throughout a good percentage of Web browsers, and mobile operating systems."*  That is a lot to support.  Note that Java is only supported in some limited form on Android, and not at all on iOS or various other mobile OS'.

Comment: And what do you mean by running in web browsers? Is this a client app or a web app? How are you with java in general?

Answer (score 0):

The Spotify Apps API does not support running Java (assuming you mean Java and not JavaScript) inside the Spotify app.

If you're running a standalone Java app, you can develop a JNI wrapper to talk to libSpotify to integrate with Spotify that way.